# How to create a shortcode with this code?

Tags: wordpress

How do I create a `shortcode` with this code here?

When I carry and I put the category in the post he carries the groups and attributes.
He is a spreadsheet with Profits and Losses based on category, attributes and groups.
The goal and create a ' shortcode ' to be loaded in a search form, where the form creates a new post and send to database with a value so this pattern!

```
a:2:{i:57;s:8:"situação";i:61;s:8:"condição";}
```

Remembering to generate this code was escolhidoa option

```
//make text input field
```

This complete code below:

```
<div id="real-tb-attributes" class="real-tab-content">

<?php $cats = get_product_cats($post->ID);

    if ($cats) {
        $cat = $cats[62];
        $cat_id = $cat->term_id;
    }  ?>

                    <?php if ($cat) {
                        // get cat groups
                        $groups = get_real_cat_groups($cat_id);
                        $groups_data = get_real_groups_data();
                        $attrs_data = get_real_attributes_data();

                        if (real_is_array($groups)) {
                            $count = 0; ?>
                            <ul class="real-data-pils">
                                <?php foreach ($groups as $group) { ?>
                                    <li data-pil="#real-pil-<?php echo $group; ?>"<?php if ($count == 0) echo ' class="active"'; ?>><?php echo $groups_data[$group]['name']; ?></li>
                                    <?php $count++;
                                } ?>
                            </ul>

                            <div class="real-pil-container">
                                <?php $count = 0;
                                foreach ($groups as $group) {
                                    $group_data = $groups_data[$group];
                                    $group_values = get_real_product_attributes($post->ID, $group); ?>
                                    <div id="real-pil-<?php echo $group; ?>" class="real-pil-content<?php if ($count == 0) echo ' active'; ?>">
                                        <?php if ($group_data['attrs']) { ?>
                                            <div class="real-group-inputs">
                                                <ul class="real-input-filelds">
                                                    <?php if (real_is_array($group_data['attrs'])) {
                                                        foreach ($group_data['attrs'] as $attr_id) {
                                                            $attr = $attrs_data[$attr_id];
                                                            $attr_val = (isset($group_values[$attr_id])) ? $group_values[$attr_id] : ''; ?>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <div class="real-col-1">
                                                                    <label for="attr-input-<?php echo $attr_id; ?>"><?php echo $attr['name']; ?></label>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="real-col-5">
                                                                    <?php // switch the input types
                                                                    switch ($attr['meta']['type']) {
                                                                        case 'text' :
                                                                            // make text input field
                                                                            echo '<input type="text" id="attr-input-' .$attr_id .'" name="real-attr[' .$group .'][' .$attr_id .']" class="real-text-input" value="' .$attr_val .'" />';
                                                                        break;

                                                                        case 'check' :
                                                                            // make checkbox input field
                                                                            echo '<input type="hidden" name="real-attr[' .$group .'][' .$attr_id .']" value="No" />';
                                                                            echo '<input type="checkbox" id="attr-input-' .$attr_id .'" name="real-attr[' .$group .'][' .$attr_id .']" class="real-checkbox" value="Yes"' .(($attr_val == 'Yes') ? ' checked="checked"' : '') .' />';
                                                                        break;

                                                                        case 'date' :
                                                                            // make date input field
                                                                            echo '<input type="text" id="attr-input-' .$attr_id .'" name="real-attr[' .$group .'][' .$attr_id .']" class="real-date-input real-text-input" value="' .$attr_val .'" />';
                                                                        break;

                                                                        case 'textarea' :
                                                                            // make textarea input field
                                                                            echo '<textarea id="attr-input-' .$attr_id .'" name="real-attr[' .$group .'][' .$attr_id .']" class="real-textarea" rows="4">' .$attr_val .'</textarea>';
                                                                        break;

                                                                        case 'select' :
                                                                            // make select box
                                                                            echo '<div class="real-select-label"><select id="attr-input-' .$attr_id .'" name="real-attr[' .$group .'][' .$attr_id .']" class="real-select-box">';
                                                                            foreach ($attr['meta']['options'] as $option) {
                                                                                echo '<option value="' .$option .'"' .(($option == $attr_val) ? ' selected="selected"' : '') .'>' .$option .'</option>';
                                                                            }
                                                                            echo '</select></div>';
                                                                        break;

                                                                        case 'mselect' :
                                                                            // make multi select box
                                                                            $attr_val = (array) $attr_val;
                                                                            echo '<select id="attr-input-' .$attr_id .'" name="real-attr[' .$group .'][' .$attr_id .']" size="' .count($attr['meta']['options']) .'" class="real-select-box" multiple>';
                                                                            foreach ($attr['meta']['options'] as $option) {
                                                                                echo '<option value="' .$option .'"' .((in_array($option, $attr_val)) ? ' selected="selected"' : '') .'>' .$option .'</option>';
                                                                            }
                                                                            echo '</select>';
                                                                        break;
                                                                    } ?>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </li>
                                                        <?php }
                                                    } ?>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php $count++;
                                } ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <p><?php _e('No Groups found for this category, you may add groups by editing category.', 'real-text'); ?></p>
                        <?php }
                    } else { ?>
                        <p><?php _e('Please select a Category to continue.', 'real-text'); ?></p>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
```

Note: google translator

I thank you

Comment: Hi, could you please explain what you want to do and what is wrong? Examples are also welcome too

Comment: edited better see if you can help me now

Comment: That's an unreadable wall of code. Machine translation only makes things worse... Do you know how to make a shortcode? Tip: shortcodes don't `echo` anything, you must `return` a HTML string.

Answer (score 0):

You better refer the official [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

create a shortcode :

```html
// [bartag foo="foo-value"]
function bartag_func( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'foo' => 'something',
        'bar' => 'something else',
    ), $atts );

    return "foo = {$a['foo']}";
}
add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' );
```